# Core data - Fetching first 20 data from sub entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm trying to build the application where user logs in and create records to the database. 
All the data are stored locally and each user logging in can have separate records.

So I build the Core data entity with the following schema.

```
User
1. Email (Primary)
2. First name
3. Last name

Record
1. Id (Primary)
2. Image
3. Title
4. Message
5. Created Date

User -> To many relationship with  -> Records
```

My scenario is after the user logged in, I need to display the user full name and first 20 records in the home page.

I fetch the user details from the database by using the email, But the problem is whenever I fetch the user detail it also fetches all the records. In some cases the record count is big say 50000.

Is there any way that I can get the user details along with only first 20 records?
Do I need to change database schema to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First 20 records based on which order? Be aware that records in Core Data are stored unordered. You need a predicate to filter records.

Comment: @vadian yes correct. I also using createdDate in the record table for filtering.

Comment: Then use the `fetchLimit` property in the fetch request

Comment: Use the inverse relationship from the record to the user with a fetchlimit and a sort

Comment: @vadian, Paulw11 I only fetch the user table, but automatically records also comes with it. How to apply fetch limit to records when I fetch user.

Comment: I got the idea from @Martin R. I will use one query for User to fetch only first name and last name using propertyToFetch. And use another query for Record to fetch first 20 records.